# How to write a mysql query to replace white spaces followed by comma in a field

Tags: mysql, string, whitespace

I have a field called dates which contains data like this `"27 Mar 2013,        28 Mar 2013,        29 Mar 2013"`

Now i need to write query to change the data to below format.

`"27 Mar 2013,28 Mar 2013,29 Mar 2013"`.

How to write a query to replace white spaces follows by comma in MySql.

Comment: how do you want to replace your string? both strings are identical

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try,

```
SELECT REPLACE(columnName, ', ', ',')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9117d/2)

Comment: No, [this demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1212a/3) also works fine

Comment: @Vinay - The point being?